# migrate RoR Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

have a existing Rails project, which was build on version 2.3.4.
On my local machine a have Rails version 3.0.3.
When a call rake db:migrate in the terminal, then the terminal replies following:

> Missing the Rails 2.3.4 gem. Please `gem install -v=2.3.4 rails`, update your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the Rails version you do have installed, or comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION to use the latest version installed.

A new created Project can be invoked by rake db:migrate
How can get running this project?

Answer (score 2):

`rake db:migrate` loads up the rails environment, which loads up your gems, for which on this project rails 2.3.4 is used.

try using [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) to manage your projects, or you need to do `gem install -v=2.3.4 rails` to get this running. If that version is installed, rubygems will load it for you.

Comment: can I upgrade the old project to 3.0.3??

Comment: it really depends on the size of the project, the amount of obtrusive javascript, etc. Generally, its not an simple process. If its a real simple app you might be able to just copy over the core app/ folder and be close. google 'upgrading to rails 3 guides' and there are some official resources.